# How is the "for" statement constructed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Everybody is aware of the most common use of for: (0 - 9)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

however, I've also seen some less common versions, like (1 - 10)

```
for (int i = 0; i++ < 10;)
```

or (1 - 10)

```
int i = 0;
for (;i++ < 10;)
```

Which would suggest that loops might be more customizable than I thought. If I'm guessing this correctly, it would seem that

1. There always needs to be 2 semicolons to separate 3 optional statements
2. The second statement needs to be convertible to boolean 1 for the loop to continue
3. The first statement is the only one where I can declare variables and is called once
4. The third and second statement are called after every iteration and can contain whatever (aside from declarations)
5. As far as those conditions are met, I can do whatever

for instance (0, 3, 7)

```
for (int i = 0, j = 2; i < 10; i+=++j)
```

Are those kinds of for loops considered standard use of the language? or just things that happen to work due to the implementation design in msvc++? Any official instructions on what the rules of for loop really are?

Comment: That is good for start with for: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Comment: I would use a while loop for your third example as all you are using is the conditional part.

Comment: I don't understand your question(s). It's already pretty well documented, what the for loop expression parts are, and when they're executed. You need the semicolons to indicate parts you want to leave out, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ISO C99 draft:

> `for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 )` statement behaves as
>   follows:
>
> The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression
>   that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
>
> The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after each
>   execution of the loop body.
>
> If clause-1 is a declaration, the scope of
>   any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and
>   the entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is reached in
>   the order of execution before the first evaluation of the controlling
>   expression.
>
> If clause-1 is an expression, it is evaluated as a void
>   expression before the first evaluation of the controlling
>   expression.
>
> Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. An
>   omitted expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.

To answer your questions:

1. There always needs to be 2 semicolons to separate 3 optional statements

   Yes.
2. The second statement needs to be convertible to boolean 1 for the loop to continue.

   Yes. The second statement will evaluate as a boolean true/false (although not necessarily "1").
3. The first statement is the only one where I can declare variables and is called once

   For C++, yes.  In C (before C99), you had to declare the variable outside of the for loop.
4. The third and second statement are called after every iteration and can contain whatever (aside from declarations)

   Yes.  And they may contain nothing.  For example, `for ( ;; )` means "loop forever".
   As far as those conditions are met, I can do whatever

Here is a good tutorial:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Comment: `for(int x:vec)` would like a word with "There always needs to be 2 semicolons to separate 3 optional statements"

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. However...

Just because it is possible doesn't mean you should do it. The entire purpose of a "for" loop is it is supposed to be organized at a level any competent programmer can understand quickly. A key fundamental is the programmer should know how long a "for" loop will run. If you add more complexity to that which is taught, the point of the "for" loop is lost. I cannot easily look at your 3rd example and tell how long the loop will iterate.

If you need to use a "for" loop like your 3rd example, you'd be better off writing a while/do-while loop.

Answer (score 2):

One of my personal favourites is to iterate over a linked list:

```
for(Node *p = head; p; p = p->next)  ...
```

And of course, if you do "no condition", you get an inifinite loop:

```
for(;;) ...
```

But yes, as long as you have `for(` following by valid statements, two semicolons and `)`, it's "good code".

```
for(printf("h"); !printf("world\n"); printf("ello, "));
```

is valid, if rather bizarre C-code (and C++, but `cout` is preferred there).

Of course, "it compiles and does what you expect" does not make it RIGHT or a good use of the language. It's often preferred if other people can read the code and understand what it's meant to do, and not want to go work somewhere else or to perform violence against the person that originally wrote the code.

Comment: I'd actually prefer `for(Node *p = head; p != nullptr; p = p->next)` The `p = p->next` is a neat increment though.

Comment: Sure, you can write out the longer `p != nullptr;` if you like. It does exactly the same thing, but makes it a bit clearer [my work would actually allow the overall construct, but `nullptr != p;` would be required in the loop]

Comment: Why print `"hworld\n"`?  Seems strange.  I guess it is an accidental demonstration of why fancy for loops are a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to do it. C++ is flexible and allows you to build statements as you wish. Of course, clearer ways as preferable.

The "for" statement has 3 parts separated by ";" character:

1) initialize code (int i = 0): where you init the counter variable(s) you're gonna use in your loop;

2) condition for loop (i < 20): condition that will be tested for the loop to continue;

3) step (increment): you can optionally specify an increment to the counter variable;

The "for" statement has preferable and indicated use when you know how much times you're going to iterate (to loop). Otherwise, it's recommended to use "while".

Example of flexibility of C++:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { }
```

is equivalent to

```
int i = 0;    
for(;i < 20;) { i++; }
```